# How to start chrome driver using selenium-maven-plugin to start Selenium server

Tags: java, maven, selenium-rc, selenium-chromedriver

I apologize first of all if this subject is being treated in another post but i have been looking for the solution like two days and I was not able to get it.

I have added a new profile to my POM in whick I use the selenium-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start-server</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <background>true</background>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <systemProperties>
                    <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Them in properties I have added the path where chromedriver is placed.

When I execute mvn clean install, I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(Ljava/net/URL;JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)V
Command duration or timeout: 434 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d185a80fa4206dfeab80ba773c04ac33c0', time: '2013-02-27 13:51:26'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at com.qa.framework.drivers.multidevice.webdriver.MultiDeviceWebDriver.setWebDriver(MultiDeviceWebDriver.java:191)
    at com.qa.framework.drivers.web.WebDriver.launchBrowser(WebDriver.java:249)
    at com.qa.games.tests.BaseTest.beforeTestCase(BaseTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:551)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:640)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(Ljava/net/URL;JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.start(ChromeDriverService.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeCommandExecutor.execute(ChromeCommandExecutor.java:48)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:432)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.callConstructor(DefaultDriverFactory.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:184)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:151)
    ... 3 more
```

If instead of indicate the place of the webdriver there I add in the code: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "/Users/support/Desktop/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/chromedriver.exe" );`, then is returning that webdriver.chrome.driver property is not defined.

I have tried as well execute `mvn clean install -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="path/chromedriver"` as as well is returning the same error.

I have tried setting the chromedriver in different paths, without .exe and with .exe.

I don't know what I'm missing, even I'm starting to think that this doesn't have any solution because if I execute my tests having selenium started by means of the following command line: `java -jar /path/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/chromedriver"`, my tests are working. I just would like not be pending on if selenium is running or not to execute my tests, but it seems it is not possible.

I would appreciate a lot if someone of you can help me on that.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?
How?

Answer (score 0):

The selenium maven plugin has been dead for over two years.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/selenium-maven-plugin/2.3

Try running with a much older version of selenium (e.g., downgrade from 2.37.0 to 2.21.0).

Comment: or should we just not use the selenium maven plugin anymore?